# What other quasi-homophones are shunned in aviation, just as "climb" is preferred to "ascend"?

Tags: terminology

What other [Rhymes](https://www.quora.com/What-are-similar-sounding-words-called/answer/Andrew-Siegel-9) does aviation spurn? [*ascend* vs. *descend*](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/50435) are  [Quasi-Homophones](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/80199), because they are stems  that  share the root *-cend* from Latin [*scandere*](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=ascend).

What about *increase* vs. *decrease*? Again, they are quasi-homophones because they are stems that share the root *-crease* from Latin [*crescere*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/decrease?ref=etymonline_crossreference#etymonline_v_881).

But Germanic  [Minimal Pairs](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/80200) are quasi-homophonous too — like

- *farther* which stems from *further*.
- the participles of *lay* vs. *lie*.
- [*lose*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/lose#etymonline_v_12441) vs. *loose* (from Proto-Germanic **lausa-*).
- *than* vs. *then*.
- *through* that stems from *thorough*. *though* doesn't etymologically relate to *through, thorough* — but all three are confused, because they are spelled so alike.
- *to* vs. *too*.

I am not a linguist. I cannot distinguish between [base vs. stem vs. root](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/9428). If I mistake linguistics terms, just edit and correct my post. Thanks!

Comment: Aviators say `Niner` for the number 9 because `nine` sounds like `no` in German.

Comment: I was also taught to say 'a'ffirmative with a hard 'a'.  If you say it without the hard 'a; it could sound like unaffirmative.

Comment: No it's because was easy to confuse with nine with five in the days of "bwa bwa bwa" crappy audio in VHF and HF comms.  Modern ATC audio is so clear these days, you often hear nine just spoken as nine.

Comment: This seems like a better question for a linguistics site...

Comment: "Increase" and "decrease" aren't shunned, they are used in speed instructions. "In-" and "de-" sound different enough to make it clear, unless the first part of the word is cut off; then the stated speed itself should make it clear (relative speed commands are not used). Interesting question!

Comment: I'm voting to close this as it's unfocused. Right now the scope could be any of the hundreds of major languages in the world used for local flying. Also, list based questions are a bad fit for the site.

Comment: IIRC @wbeard52 aviators say niner because nine and five are too close and can be misread over static.

Comment: In Dutch, 7 and 9 are pronounced (English-approximately) zayvun and nay[ch]en (ch as in J. S. Bach).  But when the telephone was introduced there, over that crackly channel 7 quickly became zoovun.  A good answer would cite a precompiled list of such things, instead of making one from scratch.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is unbounded in scope. There could be many answers, all equally correct. We would need to compile a wiki-like list. The site's format is unfortunately not suited for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience, the dissimilarity of the words are an asset to increasing clarity. Climb vs descend is (in my opinion) much more distinctive than ascend vs descend. Speed restrictions are increase vs reduce instead of increase vs decrease.

The worst aviation disaster (Tenerife) occurred after the controller said, "hold for takeoff." The correct phraseology at the time was,"taxi into position and hold." KLM thought they were cleared for takeoff and the results were tragic. Runway operations should not include the term "takeoff" unless an aircraft is being cleared for takeoff.

In short, dissimilarity increases clarity and reduces risk in aviation operations.